# Parse string into XML doc for viewing

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I am seeking to parse a string into an XML doc to view for validity prior to making a POST for update. I am a bit of a noob with google apps script and would value a little help. Please see my code below

```
function createXml() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"),
      activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      refDatasrc = ss.getSheetByName("Student"),
      refDataRange = refDatasrc.getDataRange(),
      values = refDataRange.getValues();
      var xmlst = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><List Name=GS Test" Department="First Department"><Columns><Rows>';
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
//     var child = XmlService.createElement('value');
      if(i < 1){
      var xmlCol = '<c>' + values[0][0] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][1] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][2] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][3] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][4] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][5] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][6] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][7] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][8] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][9] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][10] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][11] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][12] + '</c>'
            + '<c>' + values[0][13] + '</c>' 
            + '<c>' + values[0][14] + '</c></Columns><Rows>';
            xmlst += xmlCol;
      }     
      else
      {
      var xmlRows = '<r><v>' + values[i][0] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][1] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][2] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][3] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][4] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][5] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][6] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][7] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][8] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][9] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][10] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][11] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][12] + '</v>'
            + '<v>' + values[i][13] + '</v>' 
            + '<v>' + values[i][14] + '</v></r>';
        xmlst += xmlRows;
      }
   }
   xmlst += '</Rows>';
   Logger.log(xmlst);
```

Below is my attempt to parse the string into an XML document

```
 var document = XmlService.parse(xmlst);
 var output = XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(document);
```

I keep receiving that the XMLService is not defined. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is just a case sensitivity issue, change the first line to:

```
root = XmlService.parse(xmlst);
```

Note the lower case "ml".

Here is the Xml Service documentation which shows both how to parse an existing XML String and also the correct way to build a new xml document from scratch.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/

Comment: That did make the error vanish but how should I properly use XmlService to create the xml doc?

Comment: Rather than build the XML as a string, you should use XmlService.createElement()  along with Element.SetText() and Element.addContent() to build the entire XML structure.  However, building as a string as in your example, and then parsing it, should also work.  I've added a link to the XmlService documentation to my answer, there is an example there of building a XML document with the structure <threads><thread> thread1 </thread><thread> thread 2</thread></threads>